# ASP.NET MVC - Having trouble obtaining pull-down selection in control

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am having trouble accessing a user's pull-down selection from within the controller once the user has selected a value and submitted it via the view.
The pull-down menu is populating correctly and I've written a simple JavaScript function that alerts the user when a selection change is made. Via the alert, I see the RoleID value.  I just can't seem to access it in the controller. Please see my code below and help!  Thank you in advance.

Model:

```
public class dbModels
    public class UserAccessRequestViewModel
    {
        dbEntities _dbEntities = new dbEntities();

        public IEnumerable<ActiveRoles> Roles { get; set}
        public Guid selectedRoleID { get; set:}

        public class ActiveRoles
        {
            public Guid RoleID { get; set; }
            public string RoleName { get; set; }
        }

        public List<ActiveRoles> GetActiveRoles()
        {
            var ActiveRoles = dbEntities.LU_ROLE.Where(x => x.ACTIVE)
            .Select (x => new ActiveRoles { RoleID = x.ROLE_ID, RoleName = x.ROLE_NAME }).ToArray();
            return  activeRoles.ToList();
        }
    }
```

View:

```
<div class="text-left" style="margin:4px; padding:4px">
  <h2>Assign Role</h2>  
  @Html.DropDownList(model => model.selectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName"), new { @onchange = getUserRoleID(this)" })
</div>

<div class="form-actions no-color" style="margin:4px; padding:4px">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Approve", "UserAccessRequestManagement", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Control:

```
public class UserAccessRequestManagementController : Controller
    dbModels.UserAccessRequestViewModel _UserAccessRequestViewModel = new dbModels.UserAccessRequestViewModel();

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Approve")]
    public ActionResult Approve(Guid id)
    {
        Guid RoleID = _UserAccessRequestViewModel.selectedRoleID;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select input should be  part of your form.

```
<div class="form-actions no-color" style="margin:4px; padding:4px">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Approve", "UserAccessRequestManagement", FormMethod.Post))
    {

     <div class="text-left" style="margin:4px; padding:4px">
         <h2>Assign Role</h2>  
               @Html.DropDownList(model => model.selectedRoleID, new SelectList(Model.Roles, "RoleID", "RoleName"), new { @onchange = getUserRoleID(this)" })
     </div>
        <input type="submit" value="Approve" class="btn btn-default" />
    }
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Also you have to make sure what you want to get in your Controller action as  a parameter. 
If you just need a guid then change the parameter name to selectedRoleID as the name of the input element should match with your action parameter. In case you want to take entire model as parameter then you have to mention it correctly in action defintion.

**In case you want to get entire model in your POST action**

```
public class UserAccessRequestManagementController : Controller
    dbModels.UserAccessRequestViewModel _UserAccessRequestViewModel = new dbModels.UserAccessRequestViewModel();

    [HttpPost, ActionName("Approve")]
    public ActionResult Approve(UserAccessRequestViewModel model)
    {
        Guid RoleID = model.selectedRoleID;
    }
```

OR make it like this **In case you just want a selected guid in your POST action**

```
[HttpPost, ActionName("Approve")]
public ActionResult Approve(Guid selectedRoleID)
{
    Guid RoleID = selectedRoleID
}
```

Comment: I have made the suggested change to include the whole model and it worked perfectly for the roleID.  I voted the answer up, but it doesn't display publicly due to the fact I have less than 15 reputation (I'm a new user).

Comment: Prior to passing the whole model, I was passing the UserRequestID, so I'm now trying to figure the best way to pass this value.  I think I may need to create an @Html.HiddenFor with the UserRequestID being placed into the model.

Comment: I have used the solution and built upon it.  All is working perfectly.  Thank you so much!